# Unity built-in Packages Compiler Errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I just started learning how to use Unity to make a simple 3D game.
It's working fine when it comes to creating the environment, but once I imported the built-in Character package it gave me a compiler error and wouldn't run (All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!).
Removing the imported package removes the error and it can run, I tried using other built-in packages like 2D or Cameras but same problem occurred. 
 
 
After adding 2D package, here's the console (error with no text):
[image: Compiler Error]
After adding a character from the package, here's what the Inspector says (the associated script cannot be loaded. please fix all compiler errors and assign a valid script):
[image: Script can not be loaded]
As shown in the pictures I'm using unity 5.6.0f3 64-bit.
I tried uninstalling and re-downloading it again but that didn't work.
I tried creating a new empty project, import a package and hit run, still didn't work.

[image: code file]

Comment: It seems the two scripts on the character are not supported in Unity3D 5.6.0f3. Doesn't the console window show any compile error?

Comment: You are importing a 2D character into a 3D game..

Comment: @zwcloud no more additional errors, just the one in the first picture with no text which was already there before adding the character.

Comment: Did you download the package from the asset store? What's the link to the asset?

Comment: @Hristo I was trying different packages, Same thing happens when you have an empty run-able project but you import the built-in Character package, it gives an empty compiler error as well like in pic 1.. then if you add a First Person Character for example you get the same message script message shown earlier in pic 2 in the Inspector for the "First Person Controller (Script).. I tried adding more pictures to the post but it wouldn't let me add more than 2 since I need more reputations.

Comment: Could you create a new project (select 2D when prompted, **not** 3D) and import the same asset for the `Robot Boy` and confirm that the error still appears? Thanks.

Comment: @zwcloud I downloaded the installer from here: https://store.unity.com/download?ref=personal , and during installing everything was downloaded. I didn't change anything default except for the components. I chose the following: Unity 5.6.0f3 & Documentation & Standard Assets & Example Projects & Android Build Support & IOS Build Support & Linux Build Support & Windows Store .NET Scripting Backend & Windows Store IL2CPP Scripting Backend.

Comment: @Hristo Just tried that, same problem.. once I imported 2D the compile error with no text appeared (It's not run-able anymore), and then if I add the Robot it gives the same script messages in the Inspector.

Comment: The error does have text, you need to Unpress the _Collapse_ button in the `Console` output. Please post the error message, thanks

Comment: @Hristo Wouldn't show anything, weather _Collapse_ is pressed or not.

Comment: It seems an identical issue like [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1102593/compile-error-with-empty-message-version-522f1.html). And.. can you check if the script file name is the same with the class name in the file? They should be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working solution from [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/comments/1340655/view.html).

> Hi, I reported this as a bug and I just got the response from Unity today. Try **changing system locale to not Arabic**. Go to Control Panel > Change date, time or number format> Administrative tab> Change system locale

---

Check if the script file name is the same as the class name in the file? They should be the same.

[image: scripts]

**UPDATE**

See this part of the picture.

[image]

> No Monobehaviour scripts in the file, or the names do not match the file name.

And from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/376813/view.html),

> MonoBehaviours inside namespaces break, if they have a method with a default parameter (such as public void Foo(bool bar=true)).

See also [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1006100/view.html).

---

And it seems an identical issue of [Compile Error with empty message](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1102593/compile-error-with-empty-message-version-522f1.html).

**Solution from the post:**

> Could get a Error message on another computer and it's the same as
>   mentioned in this Thread:
>   [Creating managed DLL for Unity fails with error when importing into Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798455/creating-managed-dll-for-unity-fails-with-error-when-importing-into-unity)
>
> Which lead to this:
>   http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/5-2-1p3-mono-cecil-assemblyresolutionexception-unityengine-ui-dll.361666/
>
> I could actually solve it with manually deleting all remains of Unity
>   and Monodevelop after the deinstallation (ex.
>   C:\Users[YourUserName]\AppData\Local etc. ) and then reinstalling
>   5.2.3f.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently trying that. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, is there something else that I must have installed along Unity so the compiler would work?

Comment: Does the script file name is the same as the class name in the file?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to Unity, but do you mean this? https://ibb.co/iHC3fk (I hope I'm allowed to add external links in stackoverflow)

Comment: Nothing happens except that this message pops up for a few seconds: "All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!" https://ibb.co/fFeoD5

Comment: I just tried to make a new project and add new script like this one: https://ibb.co/mdr1Y5 it caused the same empty compiler error and as you can see it shows 'No Monobehaviour scripts in the file, or the names do not match the file name.' as well

Comment: Try install _Unity3D Editor_ only without any other components when install Unity3D. Maybe some incompatible dll in other components breaks Unity3D. @IbraheemTuffaha If this still doesn't work, install Unity3D 5.5 instead.

Comment: I found the solution on this comment here (Third link you posted):
http://answers.unity3d.com/comments/1340655/view.html
"Hi, I reported this as a bug and I just got the response from Unity today. Try changing system locale to not Arabic Go to Control Panel > Change date, time or number format> Administrative tab> Change system locale This solved the problem for me."
Which I changed _system locale_ from **Arabic (Jordan)** to **English (United States)**.
Not sure why this causes a bug but I'm glad it's finally gone! @zwcloud Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That's great. I'm also curious about why it happens. I have updated the solution in the answer.