# Unable to fix monobehaviour scripts problem in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was just getting started with Unity and using it's Standard Assets library. I used its rollerball object, but both its Ball and BallUserControl scripts gave me the following error:

> No Monobehaviour scripts in the file, or the names do not match the file name.

I didn't change any scripts, and I have no other objects or scripts in my environment. The class names match the file names. I am sure I am missing something obvious (being so new). What are some possible errors?
I am running the latest version of unity on windows 10.

Here's the BallUserControl script, as requested:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Ball
{
    public class BallUserControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Ball ball; // Reference to the ball controller.

        private Vector3 move;
        // the world-relative desired move direction, calculated from the camForward and user input.

        private Transform cam; // A reference to the main camera in the scenes transform
        private Vector3 camForward; // The current forward direction of the camera
        private bool jump; // whether the jump button is currently pressed


        private void Awake()
        {
            // Set up the reference.
            ball = GetComponent<Ball>();


            // get the transform of the main camera
            if (Camera.main != null)
            {
                cam = Camera.main.transform;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(
                    "Warning: no main camera found. Ball needs a Camera tagged \"MainCamera\", for camera-relative controls.");
                // we use world-relative controls in this case, which may not be what the user wants, but hey, we warned them!
            }
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            // Get the axis and jump input.

            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
            jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("Jump");

            // calculate move direction
            if (cam != null)
            {
                // calculate camera relative direction to move:
                camForward = Vector3.Scale(cam.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
                move = (v*camForward + h*cam.right).normalized;
            }
            else
            {
                // we use world-relative directions in the case of no main camera
                move = (v*Vector3.forward + h*Vector3.right).normalized;
            }
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // Call the Move function of the ball controller
            ball.Move(move, jump);
            jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upload the BallUserControl script

Comment: Updated my question to include the script. Please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Which UnityVersion are you using? Is the Asset compatible with it? They say [CrossPlatformInputManager is deprecated](https://forum.unity.com/threads/crossplatforminput-deprecated.539339/)

Comment: I am not getting that error. I imported the asset from within unity itself. I am using 2019.3.0a7 version.

Comment: Are you sure the name of the script in project files is exactly the same as BallUserControll.cs because of its case sensitive and make sure it does't have any spaces. And is this problem occurring for only this script or all other script that ou have created ?

Comment: It's only occurring or these two scripts. I got these scripts from the Standard Assets library, so I assumed they are fine. Just to be sure, I double checked and copy pasted the class name onto the filename. It didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Click on assets -> refresh check if it solved

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. I completely exited out of Unity and reopened the project to be doubly sure, and the error was still there.

Comment: Go to Edit> Preferences > External Tools> External Script Editor:Select Mono Develop built in

Comment: I don't have that option in external script editor. I have Open by file extension and Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Doesn't have to be related directly to the issue but in general: [`2019.3.0a7`](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/alpha/2019.3.0a7) is an **alpha** version (thus the little `a`). As any other alpha version it is for **testing new features only** and not stable for production. It is not unlikely that it is full of little errors and bugs .. that's the whole purpose of having alpha and beta versions. Checkout the section `Known Issues` on that page. If you want to actually use Unity for creating something stick with the latest stable version - currently `2019.1.8`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity built-in Packages Compiler Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403709/unity-built-in-packages-compiler-errors)

Answer (score 0):

If monobeviour files are missing or not showing in the visual studio and creates error,  Go to **Edit/Preferences/External Tools/ select visual studio version and
Regenerate project files.** It worked for me.